# Can't Display Captured Image to an other Activity, how to make it work?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, camera, photo

I want to capture an image from custom camera and then display it on an other activity where i can add other png emoticons, i have this code but it doesnt show any photo after activity launches

Answer (score 0):

Please see some changes which i have done in your code.

**1.** please call new Intent after taking photo and the pass the filepath as i do.

MainActivity :

```
  ImageView mCaptureButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        mCaptureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // get an image from the came
                        mCamPreview.captureImage(MainActivity.this);
    //starting(); // don't call Intent here
            }       
        });

    }
```

CameraPreview class:

```
private Activity _activity ;
    public void captureImage(Activity activity){
this._activity = activity;
    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mJpegCallback);
}

PictureCallback mJpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
     public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

        // Store bitmap to local storage
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            // Prepare file path to store bitmap
            // This will create Pictures/MY_APP_NAME_DIR/
            File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "AVORI");
            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "failed to create directory");
                    return;
                }
            }

            // Bitmap will be stored at /Pictures/MY_APP_NAME_DIR/YOUR_FILE_NAME.jpg
            String filePath = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "Av.jpg";
            out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
//call EditPicture.class here
 Intent i = new Intent(_activity, EditPicture.class);
    i.putExtra("FILE_PATH", filePath );
startActivity(i); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: it shows me error when i put intent there, any idea ?

Comment: What error it shows?
You need to pass CameraPreview.this as context

Comment: it shows the Constructor Intent (CameraPreview class<EditPicture>) is undefined, i tried with CameraPreview.this, EditPicture.class

Comment: Again it shows me error at both in the Main Activity, and in Camera Preview, 
in Camera Preview i did this, 
protected MainActivity mActivity;

Intent i = new INtent (mActivity, EditPicture.class); etc... 

but it shows me error on both sides, sorry to be such an annoying but i just have no idea what's going wrong , could you please try again to help me ?

Comment: Use this Activity mActivity; Intent i = new INtent (mActivity, EditPicture.class);
and have you did this    public void captureImage(Activity activity){
this.mActivity= activity;
    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mJpegCallback);
}

Comment: i forgot to say that, it shows me error at the StartActivity(i), it shows me the method startActivity(intent) is undefined for the type new Camera.PictureCallback,!

Comment: mActivity.startActivity(intent);
Try this

Comment: i tried, it captures the image, but stops there, i can see the capture button on screen, , so hard to get it work, what is going wrong ?

Comment: No, there;s no any error, the code in logcat is yellow, that's all,

Comment: So what you wanna do after captured?

Comment: to display it in an other activity, as a preview and to add png emoticons over it, like smile, sad, this things, but to be previewed like it is in snapchat after capture it shows how many seconds to display ,, put text this things,  i want a simillar preview window where i can add emoticon